# Wordpress how to use post type as page with Permalink?

Tags: wordpress

Question is how to create a route like a node express in WordPress.
/gallery/{:id or :name} which goes to gallery page

I currently have the projects, gallery page(Both of them are using a template)

```
 /**
 * Template Name: Gallery page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage  A Theme
 * @since  A Theme 1.0
 */
```

Created a custom gallery type that contains images and that attached to the project.

**Replaced theme name with A**

```
add_action( 'init', 'gallery_post_type' );
function gallery_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'gallery',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => __('Gallery Page - gallery', 'A'),
            'singular_name'      => __('Gallery', 'A'),
            'add_new_item'       => __('Add Gallery', 'A'),
            'edit_item'          => __('Edit Gallery', 'A'),
            'new_item'           => __('New Gallery', 'A'),
            'view_item'          => __('View Gallery', 'A'),
            'search_items'       => __('Search Gallery', 'A'),
            'not_found'          => __('No Gallery Found', 'A'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Gallery found in Trash', 'A')
        ),
        'description'          => 'Gallery in the gallery page',
        'hierarchical'         => false,
        'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-networking',
        'menu_position'        => 5,
        'public'               => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'supports'             => array('title')
        ));
}
```

When a user clicks a link from a project block, I would like to change the route to a gallery page.

Something like domain/gallery/project-name/
But it keeps showing not found or nothing.
The only way to see gallery page is going domain/gallery

What should I do to create gallery/project-name?
Gallery Page - Permalink: http://wordpresslocal-clone.local/gallery/**{:name} <- Can I do something like this like node express**

Gallery post - Permalink: http://wordpresslocal-clone.local/gallery/test/

I tried this code as comment suggested

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
  function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
      add_rewrite_rule(
          'gallery/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/?$',
          'index.php?pagename=gallery&project_name=$matches[1]',
          'top' );
  }
  add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
  function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
      var_dump($query_vars);
      $query_vars[] = 'project_name';
      return $query_vars;
  }
```

Comment: Check this out. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes

Comment: I tried code similar to the comment you left but still it shows not found

Answer (score 0):

Please check this , this is working fine at my End:

```
add_action('init', 'mjt_gallery_post_init');
function mjt_gallery_post_init() {
    global $data;
    register_post_type(     
        'gallery',      
    array(          
        'labels' => array(              
        'name' => 'Gallery Page',   
        'singular_name' => 'Gallery'    
        ),  
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'gallery', 
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'gallery', 
        'with_front' => true),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author',  'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),   
        'can_export' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

and Please re-save Permalink Settings  too.

Comment: It does not work for me. You have has_archive flag. Do I need to create a file with *archive.php ?

Comment: this works in default/standard Theme, 
You can try with 
archive-gallery.php 
Please check out this forum :
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/